# I am trying to add gradient as a sublayer in view but its not resizing it equal to the view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, calayer

```
    let cellview: UIView!
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer() 
    let topColor = UIColor(red: 0.435, green: 0, blue: 0.635, alpha: 1.0)
    let bottomColor = UIColor(red: 0.255 , green: 0.043, blue: 0.373, alpha: 1.0)
    gradient.colors = [topColor.cgColor, bottomColor.cgColor]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x:0, y:0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x:0.3, y:1)
    cellview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 192, height: 160))
    gradient.frame = cellview.bounds
    gradient.masksToBounds = true
    cellview.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
```

I wrote the above code according to the code gradient should cover entire view. But this is how the gradient appearing.

[Following is the screen shot for app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3JEe.png)

Comment: You may have to do this in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: Where do those magic numbers come from?  And where are you writing those lines of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function i use to create gradients, you may find it useful

```
func createGradientBackground(gradientColor: UIColor, darkStylePreferred: Bool, viewToUse: UIView) {
    
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer(layer: viewToUse.layer)
    gradient.frame = viewToUse.bounds
    gradient.locations = [0, 1]
    
    viewToUse.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "locations")
    
    animation.toValue = [0, 0.11, 1]
    animation.fromValue = [0, 0.9, 1]
    
    if darkStylePreferred {
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.black.cgColor, gradientColor.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]
    } else {
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.white.cgColor, gradientColor.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor]
    }
    
    animation.autoreverses = true
    animation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    animation.speed = 0.015
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    gradient.add(animation, forKey: nil)
}
```

Comment: Eh, this is pretty much the exact same code as OP’s except with an animation

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, just answering my self so it might help someone later on.

All I had to do is set the gradient in func viewDidLayoutSubviews(). And this solved my issue